# Got error of 404 not found for creation of JWT token

Tags: typescript, jwt, postman, nestjs

Hello i got an error of 404 not found as mentioned in below screenshot.Am using correct path but still got the error
[image]

Here is the code of UsersService:

```
 constructor(@Inject('UserModelToken') private readonly userModel: Model<User>) { }
    async findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
        return await this.userModel.find().exec();
    }
    async findOne(payload: JwtPayload): Promise<User[]> {
        return await this.userModel.findOne({ username: payload.username }).exec();
    }
    async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
        //createUserDto.password = await this.getHash(createUserDto.password);
        const createdUser = new this.userModel(createUserDto);

        return await createdUser.save();
    }
}
```

Here is the code of AuthService:

```
constructor(private readonly jwtService: JwtService, private readonly usersService: UsersService) { }

  async createToken(user: JwtPayload) {
    // const user: JwtPayload = { email: 'test@email.com' };
    const accessToken = this.jwtService.sign(user);
    return {
      expiresIn: 3600,
      accessToken,
    };
  }

  async validateUser(payload: JwtPayload): Promise<any> {
    // Validate if token passed along with HTTP request
    // is associated with any registered account in the database
    return await this.usersService.findOne(payload);
  }

}
```

Here is the code of AuthController:

```
    @Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
    constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService, private readonly usersService: UsersService) { }

    @Post('login')
    async login(@Body() payload: JwtPayload) {
        const user = await this.usersService.findOne(payload);
        if (user) {
            //if (await this.usersService.compareHash(payload.password, user['password'])) {
                return await this.authService.createToken(payload);
        }
            else {
                throw new HttpException({
                    status: HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
                    error: 'Wrong username or password',
                }, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
        }
```

Here is the code of DTO:

```
import {IsString, IsInt,IsEmail,IsNotEmpty, IsNumberString, IsIn,IsHash} from 'class-validator'

export class CreateUserDto{
    @IsEmail()
    username:string

    @IsNotEmpty()
    password:string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your DTO you used `String` instead of `string` for password type. This probably messed up your input types.

Comment: Code updated in my question but error still remains the same